# Will Spring Boot support WAR deployment of Spring Webflux applications in the future?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I know that Spring Boot, in contrast to Spring Framework, [does not support WAR deployment for Spring WebFlux applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file). My question is simple: will it ever in the future?

My use case is this: we have a lot of customers that still live in the traditional "we deploy everything on application server X" world. So although we would like to push standalone JARs, they are not ready (yet). We heavily use Spring Boot, and would really like to continue to do so, so abandoning that is not an option.

We are building reactive applications and would like to use Spring WebFlux for that, but we still need to deploy to application servers, so that is not an option. In the meantime we avoid Spring WebFlux and simply use Controllers, which works, but is not as elegant. Hence my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no plans to support Spring WebFlux with war deployments. However, you can use reactive return types, Reactor's `Mono` and `Flux` and those from RxJava, with Spring MVC packaged and deployed as war. That will allow you to build an entire reactive pipeline as you would with WebFlux, but deployed to an application server. It doesn't give you all of the benefits of full-blown reactive (no event loop-based concurrency, for example), but it can be a good middle ground for those in your situation.